# In python: how to convert the input of a function to a string without executing it?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a python function to save time while writing some documentation on jupyter notebook. And instead of writing line by line in separate blocks, I started writing many lines of code in single blocks.

Just for formatting reasons I want to create a function which accomplish this:

```py
def printspecial(some_command):
    print(f'some_command \t{some_command}')
    
printspecial(1+1)
# what I would like to get
1+1     2
# what I get
some_command    2
```

Does anybody knows how to achieve that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `1+1` happens (resulting in 2) before `printspecial` is called.

Comment: You can't, expressions are strictly evaluated. The string `"1+1"` doesn't exist at runtime. You'll need to provide that string yourself.

Comment: As jarmod says: `1+1` is **not** the input to printspecial. The only input printspecial gets is `2`. _Some_ languages give you "macros" that can be written instead of regular functions where you have access to the AST of arguments at compilation time, but Python is not one of those languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give `printspecial()` a **string** instead and use `eval()`:

```
def printspecial(some_command):
    print("{}\t{}".format(some_command, eval(some_command)))
```

Now calling`printspecial()` with a string give us:

```
printspecial("1+1")
#outputs
1+1     2
```

You can read more on `eval()` [`here`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)

Just note that `eval()` is quite powerful and can be dangerous if misused. You can read more about that in this article: [`The dangers of eval`](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: Prefer `ast.literal_eval()`.

Comment: @Guimoute, wherever possible, yes, but the OP here isn't limiting input to literals, so it isn't possible in this case. `1+1` _isn't_ a literal, for that matter, so `ast.literal_eval()` wouldn't work for the question's stated sample input.